# Unable to count form value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I got a input like this with a numbered value

```
<input type="radio" id="ja" name="upprepas" value="0">
<input type="radio" id="ja" name="bekanta" value="2">
```

But i also have like 10 other inputs, I want to count all of the inputed values. So I tried this:

```
var select = document.querySelector('input[name="upprepas"]:checked');
console.log(select.value);
var selecto = document.querySelector('input[name="bekanta"]:checked');
console.log(selecto.value);
var selector = select.value + selecto.value;
console.log(selector.value);
```

But selector is always undefined, why is that? I thought that it maybe was a string and not an integer so I tried putting `parseInt` before select.value but it didn't work.

Comment: `document.querySelector` could return `null` if its not found or checked which will throw

Comment: selector would NOT have a value. You would be adding two strings together.

Comment: `const total = +(select?.value || 0) + +(selecto?.value || 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would need to do is replace `var selector = select.value + selecto.value;` with `var selector = parseInt(select.value) + parseInt(selecto.value);` Also use `const` or `let` instead of `var`, it's a best practice ^^

Comment: Then It does not count the value it returns 20202

Comment: Ah so the reason when I tried to paseInt the value was because I console logged selector.value, Thanks alot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **querySelectorAll** to find all of the checked radios, and loop through their values and add them up.

```js
let checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked");
let total = 0;
checked.forEach(function(e){
   total += parseInt(e.value);
});

console.log(total)
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="kreativxt" value="10"> A
<input checked type="radio" name="krexativt" value="1"> V
<input checked type="radio" name="krewativt" value="2"> C
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer aswell, now I dont have to write them all out.